# wp_remote_get: fetch data received

Tags: php, wordpress, api

I'm trying to grab specific data using this api (for a Wordpress blog):

https://api.chess.com/pub/player/erik/stats

I'm lost with arrays and am unable to isolate specific data: for example, if I want "Last" "rating" for "chess_daily". Here is the code I use, but can't figure out how to target data.

```
<?php $request = wp_remote_get( 'https://api.chess.com/pub/player/erik/stats' );
if( is_wp_error( $request ) ) {
return false; 
}
$body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request);
$test = json_decode( $body,true );
print_r ($test);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP 7 added the null coalescing operator which is a great way to get data from array. For your sample you can run:

```php
$last_chess_daily = $test['chess_daily']['last'] ?? null;
```

Which returns:

```php
array (
  'rating' => 1604,
  'date' => 1616714557,
  'rd' => 51,
)
```